# Change your mind, free your head!

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

What do the variables stand for?

$g = 12$

$h = 28$

$i = 1$

$j = 0$  (at times, $j = 1$)

$k = 4$

$l = 2$

$m = g - (k + i)$

$n = 3$

$x = gh + ij + kl + mn$

The correct answer should contain ***words only,*** not numbers.

Comment: I've turned your equations into code for MathJax, the Puzzling.SE math renderer. If you'd like to use $\times$ rather than juxtaposition to indicate multiplication, use `\times ` (with a space after).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variables stand for

> days in specific months, and months of the year.

In particular:

> $g$ is the number of months. Each month has at least $28$ days, so it's multiplied by 28 (in the variable $h$).
> $i$, $k$, and $m$ are the number of months with exactly $29$, $30$, and $31$ days respectively. $j$, $l$, and $n$ are the number of days you need to add to the original $28$ for each month in the year that has the corresponding number of days. And of course, $x$ is the number of days in the year!

Full list:

> $g$: **the number of months in the year.**
>  $h$: **the number of minimum days in each month.**
>  $i$: **the number of months with a certain number of days.** *(That number happens to be $29$, but that knowledge is not necessary to understand the equation.)*
>  $j$: **the number of additional days after the minimum for each month in category** $i$.
>  $k$: **the number of months with a certain number of days different from** $h$ **'s.** *(That number happens to be $30$, but that knowledge is not necessary to understand the equation.)*
>  $l$: **the number of additional days after the minimum for each month in category** $k$.
>  $m$: **the number of months currently unaccounted for.**
>  $n$: **the number of additional days after the minimum for each month in category** $m$.
>  $x$: **the total number of days in the year.**